# Flutter: Customizing Stepper

Tags: dart, flutter, stepper

Is there a way to change the color of the "line" between the steps? And also remove the padding to connect the "line" to the steps?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I doubt. I think your only way is create your custom `Stepper`. As you can see in sources - `Stepper` is StatefulWidget and `_StepperState` is private (these lines are Containers with height 1.0) -

```
Container( 
    margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0), 
    height: 1.0, color: Colors.grey.shade400, )
```

I don't see any way to change it

Comment: Thanks Andrey. I guess I have to customize the stepper myself.

Comment: @nypogi i have customized my stepper for this, let me know if you have any trouble.

Comment: @Andrey Turkovsky Can you provide the whole code for the custom stepper?

Comment: @KKRocks if I needed such widget - I would copy the whole class `Stepper` from `material` package into my project, change paddings or what I need else and use this class instead of material Stepper